# How can I create vectors of a standard size so I can add them to a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a single vector (call it t1) with a series of observations. I want to create a set of new vectors by popping the first observation from t1 (and so on for subsequent near-copies). But I want to keep the vectors the same length so I can add them to a data frame later.

I was able to make it work as follows:

```
t1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
t2 <- t1[-1]
t3 <- t2[-1]

t2[length(t2)+1] <- 0

t3[length(t3)+1] <- 0
t3[length(t3)+1] <- 0

t.all <- cbind(as.data.frame(t1), as.data.frame(t2), as.data.frame(t3))

t.all

  t1 t2 t3
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  0
3  3  0  0
```

But this is clumsy and it's going to be tedious if I want to create a large number of columns. How can I keep the vectors the same length (or solve this problem another way)?

Comment: Tell us more about this future data frame.  There may be much simpler ways to populate it with the subsets of `t1` you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> t.all <- sapply(0:2, function(x) c( t1[(x+1):3], rep(0,x) ) )
> t.all
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    0
[3,]    3    0    0
```

If you need it to be a data.frame it would be a lot more efficient to build as a matrix first and then wrap `as.data.frame` around the final result.

Comment: note that this solution is not general (it's only for vectors of length 3).

Comment: `sapply(0:(length(t1)-1), function(x) c(t1[(x+1):length(t1)], rep(0,x)))` seems like the obvious generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Here a loop version of what you try to do , uding `do.call` and `lapply`:

```
cbind(t1,do.call(cbind,lapply(seq_along(t1)-1,
                     function(x)c(tail(t1,-x),rep(0,x)))))


    t1    
[1,]  1 2 3
[2,]  2 3 0
[3,]  3 0 0
```

Comment: This worked with the sample data set, but with my actual data set I get the following warning and the wrong results in column 2 and 3 (they match the test data): "number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)"

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using vector indexing:

```
t1 <- (2,5,3)
mm <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(t1), function(x) t1[x:length(t1)][1:length(t1)]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    5    3
# [2,]    5    3   NA
# [3,]    3   NA   NA

mm[is.na(mm)] <- 0
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    5    3
# [2,]    5    3    0
# [3,]    3    0    0
```

Another way without using `apply` family:

```
t1 <- c(2,5,4,6)
len <- length(t1)
matrix(t1[outer(1:len, 0:(len-1), '+')], ncol=len)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    5    4    6
# [2,]    5    4    6   NA
# [3,]    4    6   NA   NA
# [4,]    6   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a matrix row-by-row, by recycling `t1` as desired:

```
tmat <-cbind(t1,t1,t1,t1,....) # as many as needed
```

Then just use a matrix triangle function

```
newmat<- tmat * upper.tri(tmat,diag=TRUE)
```

That's offset from your sample, but contains the same info per row.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers focus on creating the final data.frame. If that is your ultimate goal, then they provide good approaches. This answer instead focuses narrowly on your question of how to take the first element off and preserve the length. In order to keep things tidy, it is best to do the whole thing in one function.

```
shift <- function(tx) {append(tx[-1],0)}
```

Then you can have

```
t1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
t2 <- shift(t1)
t3 <- shift(t2)

t.all <- data.frame(t1, t2, t3)
```

which gives you the same result you had.

```
> t.all
  t1 t2 t3
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  0
3  3  0  0
```

If you want to combine this function with a looping construct to create the data.frame, it is easiest to go through a matrix first.

```
t.all <- matrix(t1, nrow=length(t1), ncol=length(t1))
lapply(seq(length=length(t1))[-1], function(i) {
  t.all[,i] <<- shift(t.all[,(i-1)])
})
t.all <- as.data.frame(t.all)
```

which gives the same data.frame, but with slightly different column names

```
> t.all
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  0
3  3  0  0
```